# Split a line having different Angles

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I want to split a line haveing zigzag(different angles) but bthere are many vertics.
I have an option in Arc GIS 10 to split from vertics but i need to split only where the angle or dimension is changed

Comment: Hamid, please clarify. What does this mean: 'where the angel or dimension is changed' ?  Sounds like a vertex, but I think you're saying you don't want to split at vertices...

Comment: you can try to generalize then splitline, arcpy.Generalize_edit("poly_line", "0.5")
arcpy.SplitLine_management("poly_line", "poly_line_split")

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few steps that might help accomplish your task-

"Simplify Line" or "Smooth line" - to remove in-line vertices.

"Feature Vertices To Points" - covert vertices to Point features.

optional - snap points to the original line if they moved during Simplify line.
(Arc 10.0, editing tools, snap)

"Split Line at Point" - break the original line.